# Transferring file from client to server

Tags: java, file, client-server

I'm trying to make a simple transfer of a text `.txt` file from client to server, and no matter how much I think I know, and understand what I'm doing, and what exactly happening, I always get it wrong. I can really use some help here please.

So, this is the code, two function that transfer a `.txt` file from one to another:
**Client side:**

```
private void sendFileToServer(String file_name) throws IOException {

    File file=new File(file_name);
    int file_size=(int)file.length();
    byte[] bytes=new byte[file_size];
    FileInputStream os=null;
    try {
        os = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The file "+file+" wasn't found");
        return;
    }
    BufferedInputStream bos=new BufferedInputStream(os);

    bos.read(bytes);
    output.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    /* 'output' is a PrintStream object, that holds the output stream
     * for the client's socket, meaning:
     * output=new PrintStream(client_socket.getOutputStream()); */
    output.flush();
    bos.close();
}
```

this will buffer everything into `BufferedInputStream`, will copy it to `bytes` and will then send it to the other side - the server.
**Server side:**

```
public static String receiveFileFromClient(Client client) throws IOException {

    int buffer_size=client.getSocket().getReceiveBufferSize();
    byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("transfered_file.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    DataInputStream in=client.getInputStream();

    int count;
    System.out.println("this will be printed out");
    while ((count=in.read(bytes))>0) { // execution is blocked here!
        bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }
    System.out.println("this will not be printed");
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();

    return "transfered_file.txt";

}
```

My intention here is to keep reading bytes from the client (the `while` loop), until the other side (the client) have no more bytes to send, and this is where in.read(bytes) should return 0 and the loop should break, but this is never happens, it just get blocked, **even though** all the bytes from the client's input-stream were successfully transferred!
Why doesn't the loop breaks?
From Javadoc:

> If no byte is available because the stream is at end of file, the
>   value -1 is returned

doesn't the last byte is considered "end of file"? I made sure that the function `sendFileToServer` properly writes the entire file to the `output` instance (PrintStream object) and returns.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand it, the read() method will block until either it read[bytes] OR the socket is closed. So there is nothing for the read() what would indicate that it should stop reading, because it does not "understand" the file, its just some data.

A solution...

You could determine the number of bytes the client will send (on the client side) and then send the NUMBER over to the server. Now the server can process this number and knows how many bytes to read before the file is complete. So you can break the loop (or even don't use a loop) when the transfer is completed.

You could also process the data the server receives, and let the client send some "flag" after the file is complete, so the server knows when it is done. But this is more difficult, because you have to find something, that is not contained in the file-byte data

Comment: Sending the number of bytes to the server is a great idea. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

read() method will block for further input if you dont close the stream. So eather close the stream, or remove the loop and only read the number of bytes, you receive from the client

Comment: I can't close the stream - I need it for further communication and data transfer between the client and the server.
and I can't remove the while loop - The server don't know how many bytes to accept from client, it can't predict the file size...

Comment: There is available() function on the stream

Comment: Or whats about to send the size in the first bytes?

Comment: Yes, I think I'll go with that. thanks for the help.